# how to plot histogram for cells of grid on x-y plane in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

**What I have done:** I have x,y,v arrays of data that which I bin in 2D x-y plane and let v values fall into the bins (or we can call them cells). Then I plot the mean of v values in each cell and make a heatmap of it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([11,12,12,13,21,14])
y=np.array([28,5,15,16,12,4])
v=np.array([10,5,2,10,6,7])

x = x // 4 
y = y // 4 
k=10
cells = [[[] for y in range(k)] for x in range(k)] #creating cells or pixels on x-y plane

#letting v values to fall into the grid cells
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = v[(y  == ycell) & (x  == xcell)]
        
#getting mean from velocity values in each cell
mean_v = [[[] for y in range(k)] for x in range(k)]
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = v[(y == ycell) & (x == xcell)]
        this = cells[ycell][xcell] 
        mean_v[ycell][xcell] = np.mean(cells[ycell][xcell]) 
        mean_pix= mean_v[ycell][xcell]       
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mean_v=np.array(mean_v)
mean_masked = np.ma.masked_where(mean_v == 0, mean_v)
plt.imshow(mean_masked, origin='lower')
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

**What I want to do:** I want to plot histograms of each of those cells that are not empty on that x-y plane. That is, I want the output plot to have the x-y axis that is seen in my attached figure, but instead of the mean colour appearing in the cells, I want to see histograms of v-values in those cells. Thanks!

UPDATE: I followed @tmdavison's way (thanks) but the plot's not quite accurate for my original data set which is different from the data set on this post. It's a large data set with v values ranging from -200 to 200 but the plot is showing inaccurate values in x and y axes for the pixels. The histograms and x,y axes labels are also overlapping which is making it hard to understand them at all.

[image]

Comment: A 2D histogram usually counts frequency so for example `matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d` would create the `v` array you have by counting the frequency of given `x` and `y` values in 2D bins.

If you loop over your `x` and `y` arrays and duplicate the values based on your existing `v` column you should be able to simply call:
`matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d(x, y)`

Comment: @Charmander35, Could you please show me using my code? I am new to coding and weak with loops. I was trying before but could not make it work.

Comment: not sure I understand exactly what you want... do you mean you want a little mini square histogram in each of the cells which are currently coloured in on your figure?

Comment: @tmdavison, yes that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the [`ax.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html) function with `transform=ax.transData`, to add new Axes instances at given locations on your existing Axes. The you can use [`ax.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html) to plot the histograms on those inset axes.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=np.array([11,12,12,13,21,14])
y=np.array([28,5,15,16,12,4])
v=np.array([10,5,2,10,6,7])

x = x // 4 
y = y // 4 
k=10

cells = [[[] for y in range(k)] for x in range(k)] #creating cells or pixels on x-y plane

#letting v values to fall into the grid cells
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = v[(y  == ycell) & (x  == xcell)]
        
#getting mean from velocity values in each cell
mean_v = [[[] for y in range(k)] for x in range(k)]
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = v[(y == ycell) & (x == xcell)]
        this = cells[ycell][xcell] 
        mean_v[ycell][xcell] = np.mean(cells[ycell][xcell]) 
        mean_pix= mean_v[ycell][xcell]       
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mean_v=np.array(mean_v)
mean_masked = np.ma.masked_where(mean_v == 0, mean_v)

# Set limits for main Axes
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Cells to loop over and create histograms for
yy, xx = np.where(mean_v > 0)

# Loop over cells
for i, j in zip(xx, yy):

    # Create inset axes. Width and height are 1 since the cells are unit cells
    axhist = ax.inset_axes([i, j, 1, 1], transform=ax.transData)

    # Plot the histogram. Here we use integer bins
    axhist.hist(v[(y==j) & (x==i)], bins=range(11), density=True)

    # Turn off ticks and labels, and set the histogram axes limits
    axhist.set_xticks([])
    axhist.set_yticks([])
    axhist.set_xlim(0, 10)
    axhist.set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

As you can see in your toy dataset, there are only one or two entries of `v` per cell for now, so the histograms aren't that exciting, but this should work for a larger dataset too.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I actually need the x and y axis of the histograms to display their respective values for each cell, so that I can understand what is the distribution of values of variable 'v' and corresponding frequency.

Comment: so you still want the tick labels? That's easy, just don't turn them off (i.e. remove the lines `axhist.set_xticks([])` and `axhist.set_yticks([])`)

Comment: when i remove the tick labels, I get a plot that's unclear and inaccurate in terms of x and y axes of the histograms in the pixels. My data has large ranges -200 to 200 but the plots are showing wrong values and they are too small to see the histograms...:( I am posting it in the original post as an update for you to see. i removed ticks and setting y and x lims for the histograms.

Comment: What is inaccurate? In my post I fixed the x limits between 0 and 10 because that what your original data had. If your actual data has different limits, of course you need to change those limits too! Regarding the histograms being too small to see, and the labels all overlapping - I'm afraid there's not much you can do about that, other than coming up with a different way to display your data...

Comment: haha I did not use x lims for 0 to 10, I commented out all 4 lines before plot.show() and ended up with an image like the one I posted in the update of my post. Then I set the y and x-axes to my specific range in my large data set which is quite large, 0 to 25000 for y axis and -200 to 200 for x axes and it shows just empty boxes for histograms. Not sure what's going on. Maybe the y lims are too huge? But that's just how the data is.

Comment: 1. In the image you posted it looks like the x limits are 0 and 10 for the cells with histograms in (although some are -0.05 to 0.05). So you might want to check where you set those limits. 2. With the `density=True` option for `ax.hist`, the area under the histogram integrates to 1. So you would probably want to change the y limits to 0-1, or change to `density=False`